# Weird Error when setting detailItem in DetailViewController from MasterViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I started getting this error randomly (may be due to updating swift) but when I reach, didSet in detailItem, I call configureView. In configureView I check to see if detailItem is indeed set and then start assigning values to my outlets.

```
if let detail: Posting = self.detailItem {
        print("detail title is ")
        println(detail.title)

        // Title
        self.titleLabel.text = detail.title
```

However this crashes with output:

```
detail title is Skiing in Vail
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The error is on the line:

```
self.titleLabel.text = detail.title
```

I don't understand why it is crashing when it is is clearly set...
Note that this doesn't happen if I call `configureView` from within viewDidLoad.

This only happens when I call it from

```
 var detailItem: Posting? {
    didSet { self.configureView() }
}
```

Something I'm missing? Is this working asynchronously or something?

Comment: It sounds a lot like an error you'll get if you try and use prepareForSegue(), then set a `someLabel.text = ""` inside the method before the given label is instantiated. In your case, are you absolutely certain that `self.titleLabel` is instantiated? In your first code example, you may add a `println(self.titleLabel.text)` to see what the value is at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, `titleLabel.text` wasn't set yet. So how should I be setting the detailItem if not in the prepareForSegue call in the masterVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing your comment on how to implement this, there are a few trains of thought. First, the reason you can modify it directly from your MasterVC is because the IBOutlet hasn't been instantiated in the DetailVC and thus isn't available to be modified yet.

One option, which I'd probably follow, is to have a helper variable on your detail view where you can place the value. Then `viewWillAppear()` you can take whatever's in the variable and set it as the label's text. Here's a tutorial on it, but to answer your specific quesiton please jump to the `prepareForSegue` method in this tutorial. It gives a good rundown of the whole process:

http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't mention it above, but I ended up just using `viewWillAppear`